# Why is my timezone conversion not working correctly when querying for events?

Tags: mongodb, heroku, mongoose, momentjs, mlab

I have a mongodb query that works just fine on my local machine, however on my production environment (Heroku) it doesn't work the same way. For example, I am in EST timezone and my production server is returning events from the previous day if they occur after 8:00 PM EST (since there is a 4 hour offset from UTC). I store all of my dates in UTC format in my mongodb database and do the conversion to local timezone when querying for data. Once again, everything works fine on my local testing environment. Here is the query I am using:

```
Event.find({
    'starts': {
       '$gte':moment(req.query.date+'T00:00:00.000').tz(req.user.tz).format(),
        '$lte':moment(req.query.date+'T23:59:59.999').tz(req.user.tz).format()
    },
})
.exec(function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('ERROR = ' + err);
    } else {
        return res.json(data);
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong? I made sure that my Heroku app is set to UTC. One other thing is that my mongo database is hosted through MongoLab. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure if this is what you're asking for, but if you want to parse using the specified time zone, then:

```
moment.tz(req.query.date,'YYYY-MM-DD',req.user.tz).format()
```